# using the fetch api with ramda

Tags: javascript, promise, functional-programming, fetch-api, ramda.js

I'm learning Ramda and try to reach pointfree programming. In order to do that, I try to refactor here and there but got stuck on this.

I obviously think this doesn't work because the call is asychronous but I could not find what is wrong with this code.

```js
// Why is this
const toJSONRamda = R.pipe(
  R.prop('json'), // getting the 'json' function
  R.call // and calling it
)

// different from this
const toJSON = response => response.json()

// Works
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(toJSON)
  .then(console.log)
  
// Does not Work
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(toJSONRamda)
  .then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that the `json` method of the response object is not a pure function.  It is really a method.  When you use `pipe(prop('json'), call)`, you are trying to call that method as a pure function.  In some circumstances that will work.  But here, the `json` method actually uses `this`.  Ramda's `call` does not supply any `this` object.

There is a Ramda alternative:

```js
const toJSONRamda = R.invoker(0, 'json')

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(toJSONRamda)
  .then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

[`invoker`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#invoker) works with methods.  These should help describe how it works:

```
R.invoker(0, 'method')(obj) = obj['method']()
R.invoker(1, 'method')(a, obj) = obj['method'](a)
R.invoker(2, 'method')(a, b, obj) = obj['method'](a, b)
//...
```

However, there is an important point not to miss.  Point-free programming is useful only so long as it improves readability.  This to me is already perfectly readable:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(console.log)
```

If this is only a learning exercise, then, by all means feel free to try to turn that into a point-free version.  But I would leave it as is for production code.

Comment: Indeed this is only for learning purposes. And I learned something new thanks to your answer. Thank you very much.